# Representing folder hierarchy with html

Tags: html, css

I'm building a web application that will show a hierarchy of things. The hierarchy will closely resemble that of a file system with folders and files, i.e. I'll have folders that contains files and subfolders in any depth level (though it will probably never go deeper than three levels).

The whole hierarchy will be shown in one view. It will be shown in a tree style and the folders can be expanded/closed by the user at will. The diffrent levels are indented, just as a standard file system browser.

What is a good way of representing this with HTML and CSS? Note that it is not the design/look itself I need help with but rather how to structure this in a good way using HTML. Should I use lists?

Answer (score 18):

An approach framed using `div` and `span`, explained below with a working example at last.

Every folder contains 2 types of contents. `Files` and inner `Folders`. So a basic structure is designed with a overall container.

**Overall Container**:

```
<div id="hierarchy">
    <!--folder structure goes here-->
</div>
```

**Folder Structure**:

```
<div class="foldercontainer">
    <span class="folder fa-folder-o" data-isexpanded="true">Folder 1</span>
    <span class="file fa-file-excel-o">File 11</span>
    <span class="file fa-file-code-o">File 12</span>
    <span class="file fa-file-pdf-o">File 13</span>
</div>
```

**Folder Structure (with no files)**:

```
<div class="foldercontainer">
    <span class="folder fa-folder">Folder 1</span>
    <span class='noitems'>No Items</span>
</div>
```

The `foldercontainer` contains `span` elements that specifies the file names. First `span` element contains the folder title, while the remaining contains the filenames. The `data-` attribute `isexpanded` specifies whether the specified folder is expanded or collapsed.

If a folder contains no files, then add the `noitems` `span` element to the structure.

While a folder contains another folder, just add the same html as a child to it. i.e.,

```
<div class="foldercontainer">
    <span class="folder fa-folder-o" data-isexpanded="true">Folder 1</span>
    <span class="file fa-file-excel-o">File 11</span>
    <span class="file fa-file-code-o">File 12</span>
    <span class="file fa-file-pdf-o">File 13</span>

    <div class="foldercontainer">
        <span class="folder fa-folder-o" data-isexpanded="true">Folder 1-1</span>
        <span class="file fa-file-excel-o">File 1-11</span>
        <span class="file fa-file-code-o">File 1-12</span>
        <span class="file fa-file-pdf-o">File 1-13</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**:

The `click` event is delegated from the parent `#hierarchy` element to the folders and files, to handle click in a single event listener. On clicking a folder, it is expanded and the icon changes. On clicking again it collapses and resets the icon.

While the inner folder is expanded and outer folder is collapsed, when expanding the outer folder, the inner folder contents states are preserved, by design.

[Refer this nice article](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm) to learn how to handle events on multiple elements in a single listener.

**Note**: The code can be altered to make use of [CSS custom variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables) and [Data attributes access to CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to be more efficient, while the former is not supported in IE and latter has its own disadvantages in cross-browser support. So use at your own risk.

**Working example with various hierarchies**:

```js
var hierarchy = document.getElementById("hierarchy");
hierarchy.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    var elem = event.target;
    if(elem.tagName.toLowerCase() == "span" && elem !== event.currentTarget)
    {
        var type = elem.classList.contains("folder") ? "folder" : "file";
        if(type=="file")
        {
            alert("File accessed");
        }
        if(type=="folder")
        {
            var isexpanded = elem.dataset.isexpanded=="true";
            if(isexpanded)
            {
                elem.classList.remove("fa-folder-o");
                elem.classList.add("fa-folder");
            }
            else
            {
                elem.classList.remove("fa-folder");
                elem.classList.add("fa-folder-o");
            }
            elem.dataset.isexpanded = !isexpanded;

            var toggleelems = [].slice.call(elem.parentElement.children);
            var classnames = "file,foldercontainer,noitems".split(",");

            toggleelems.forEach(function(element){
                if(classnames.some(function(val){return element.classList.contains(val);}))
                element.style.display = isexpanded ? "none":"block";
            });
        }
    }
});
```

```css
#hierarchy
{
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    width: 300px;
}
.foldercontainer, .file, .noitems
{
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 50px;
}
.folder
{
    color: red;
}
.file
{
    color: green;
}
.folder, .file
{
    cursor: pointer;
}
.noitems
{
    display: none;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.folder:hover,.file:hover
{
    background: yellow;
}
.folder:before, .file:before
{
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="hierarchy">
<div class="foldercontainer">
    <span class="folder fa-folder-o" data-isexpanded="true">Folder 1</span>
    <span class="file fa-file-excel-o">File 11</span>
    <span class="file fa-file-code-o">File 12</span>
    <span class="file fa-file-pdf-o">File 13</span>

    <div class="foldercontainer">
        <span class="folder fa-folder-o" data-isexpanded="true">Folder 1-1</span>
        <span class="file fa-file-excel-o">File 1-11</span>
        <span class="file fa-file-code-o">File 1-12</span>
        <span class="file fa-file-pdf-o">File 1-13</span>
    </div>

    <div class="foldercontainer">
        <span class="folder fa-folder">Folder 1-2</span>
        <span class='noitems'>No Items</span>
    </div>

    <div class="foldercontainer">
        <span class="folder fa-folder">Folder 1-3</span>
        <span class='noitems'>No Items</span>
    </div>

    <div class="foldercontainer">
        <span class="folder fa-folder">Folder 1-4</span>
        <span class='noitems'>No Items</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="foldercontainer">
    <span class="folder fa-folder-o" data-isexpanded="true">Folder 2</span>
    <span class="file fa-file-excel-o">File 21</span>
    <span class="file fa-file-code-o">File 22</span>
    <span class="file fa-file-pdf-o">File 23</span>

    <div class="foldercontainer">
        <span class="folder fa-folder-o" data-isexpanded="true">Folder 2-1</span>
        <span class="file fa-file-excel-o">File 2-11</span>
        <span class="file fa-file-code-o">File 2-12</span>
        <span class="file fa-file-pdf-o">File 2-13</span>

        <div class="foldercontainer">
            <span class="folder fa-folder">Folder 2-1-1</span>
            <span class='noitems'>No Items</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="foldercontainer">
    <span class="folder fa-folder-o" data-isexpanded="true">Folder 3</span>
    <span class="file fa-file-excel-o">File 31</span>
    <span class="file fa-file-code-o">File 32</span>
    <span class="file fa-file-pdf-o">File 33</span>

    <div class="foldercontainer">
        <span class="folder fa-folder">Folder 3-1</span>
        <span class='noitems'>No Items</span>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

The good way to represent it in HTML is to organize your file list as a... HTML list :) For example you might get this:

```
<ul>
     <li>Folder 1
           <ul>
               <li>SubFile 1</li>
               <li>SubFile 2</li>
               <li>SubFile 3</li>
           </ul></li>
     <li>Folder 2
           <ul>
               <li>SubFile 4</li>
               <li>SubFile 5</li>
               <li>SubFile 6</li>
           </ul></li>
     <li>Main File 1</li>
     <li>Main File 2</li>
</ul>
```

Then the CSS can be very soft, because the list already represents a hierarchy.

Comment: I would definitely use xml for that!

Comment: In my case, I just wrote xHTML which is some kind of XML. If he want to use this in a web application, the proper way I guess is to directly render it as HTML, to avoid another parsing.

Comment: + you can always style it with some folder images as list-style-image to make it nicer ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid `<ul>` since that's for an "un-ordered list" whereas your folder structure will likely be in some sort of order.

I'd use the Definition List, or Ordered List;

```
<dl>
    <dt>Folder 1
        <dl>
            <dt>Child 1</dt>
            <dt>Child 2</dt>
            <dt>Child 3</dt>
        </dl>
    </dt>
    <dt>Folder 2
        <dl>
            <dt>Child 1</dt>
            <dt>Child 2</dt>
            <dt>Child 3</dt>
        </dl>
    </dt>
</dl>

<ol>
    <li>Folder 1
        <ol>
            <li>Child 1</li>
            <li>Child 2</li>
            <li>Child 3</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>Folder 2
        <ol>
            <li>Child 1</li>
            <li>Child 2</li>
            <li>Child 3</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Interesting point. The user will be able to control the order of the items in the list, both the folders and the files. Does that mean that I should use an ordered list? I've never thought about it that way...

Comment: If the folders are going to be somewhat ordered, then the the semantically correct tag, imo, would be the <ol> tag - Since the list and folders would be ordered.

Answer (score 0):

```
I have created folder hierarchy using list items. This will help for sure.
```

```js
$(function() {
        setFolderHeirarchy();
    });

    function setFolderHeirarchy() {
               var labelWrapper= $('.labelWrapper');
                $(labelWrapper).each(function () {
                    if (!$(this).next('.subFolderHeirarchy')||$(this).next('.subFolderHeirarchy').length==0) {
                        $(this).find('.arrow').remove();
                    }
                    else{
                        console.log($(this).next('.subFolderHeirarchy'));
                    }
                });

     

        $('.labelWrapper').click(function() {
            if ($(this).next('.subFolderHeirarchy').length > 0) {
                $(this).parent('.folderHeirarchyList').toggleClass('active');

                if ($(this).parent('.folderHeirarchyList').hasClass('active')) {
                    $(this).find('.arrow').removeClass('glyphicon-triangle-right').addClass('glyphicon-triangle-bottom');
                } else {
                    $(this).find('.arrow').removeClass('glyphicon-triangle-bottom').addClass('glyphicon-triangle-right');
                }
            }else{
                // $(this).css('color','red');
            }

        });

    }
```

```css
.mainFolderHeirarchy li {
  border: none;
  background: 0 0!important
}

.mainFolderHeirarchy li a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none!important
}

.mainFolderHeirarchy li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none!important
}

.mainFolderHeirarchy .folderHeirarchyList {
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 3px
}

.mainFolderHeirarchy .folderHeirarchyList.active>.subFolderHeirarchy {
  display: block
}

.mainFolderHeirarchy .folderHeirarchyList .subFolderHeirarchy {
  display: none;
  padding-left: 5px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <h1> Folder Heirarchy/ multi level list item</h1>
    <hr />
    <ul class="list-group mainFolderHeirarchy">
            <li class="list-group-item folderHeirarchyList">
                <a href="#" class="labelWrapper"><span class="arrow glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right"></span><span class="listlabel">listitem</span> </a>
                <ul class="subFolderHeirarchy">
                    <li class="list-group-item folderHeirarchyList">
                        <a href="#" class="labelWrapper"><span class="arrow glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right"></span><span class="listlabel">listitem</span> </a>
                        <ul class="subFolderHeirarchy">
                            <li class="list-group-item folderHeirarchyList">
                                <a href="#" class="labelWrapper"><span class="arrow glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right"></span><span class="listlabel">listitem</span> </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-group-item folderHeirarchyList">
                                <a href="#" class="labelWrapper"><span class="arrow glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right"></span><span class="listlabel">listitem</span> </a>
                                <ul class="subFolderHeirarchy">
                                    <li class="list-group-item folderHeirarchyList">
                                        <a href="#" class="labelWrapper"><span class="arrow glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right"></span><span class="listlabel">listitem</span> </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item folderHeirarchyList">
                                        <a href="#" class="labelWrapper"><span class="arrow glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right"></span><span class="listlabel">listitem</span> </a>
                                        <ul class="subFolderHeirarchy">
                                    <li class="list-group-item folderHeirarchyList">
                                        <a href="#" class="labelWrapper"><span class="arrow glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right"></span><span class="listlabel">listitem</span> </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item folderHeirarchyList">
                                        <a href="#" class="labelWrapper"><span class="arrow glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right"></span><span class="listlabel">listitem</span> </a>
                                        <ul class="subFolderHeirarchy">
                                    <li class="list-group-item folderHeirarchyList">
                                        <a href="#" class="labelWrapper"><span class="arrow glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right"></span><span class="listlabel">listitem</span> </a>
                                        <ul class="subFolderHeirarchy">
                                    <li class="list-group-item folderHeirarchyList">
                                        <a href="#" class="labelWrapper"><span class="arrow glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right"></span><span class="listlabel">listitem</span> </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item folderHeirarchyList">
                                        <a href="#" class="labelWrapper"><span class="arrow glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right"></span><span class="listlabel">listitem</span> </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item folderHeirarchyList">
                                        <a href="#" class="labelWrapper"><span class="arrow glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right"></span><span class="listlabel">listitem</span> </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item folderHeirarchyList">
                        <a href="#" class="labelWrapper"><span class="arrow glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right"></span><span class="listlabel">listitem</span> </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a file tree with this html format:

```html
<div class="cont">

  <ul class="tree">
     <li>
   <div class="div"><i class="folder"></i>&nbsp;Folder</div>
        <ul class="branch">
        <li><i class="file"></i>&nbsp;File 1</li>
        <li><i class="file"></i>&nbsp;File 2</li>
        </ul>
     </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And with css and JavaScript:

```js
var toggler = document.getElementsByClassName("div");
var i;
var slct = "None"

for (i = 0; i < toggler.length; i++) {
  toggler[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.parentElement.querySelector(".branch").classList.toggle("active");
  });
  toggler[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    slct = this.textContent
    document.getElementById("slct").textContent = slct
  })
}
var files = document.getElementsByClassName("file")
for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  files[i].parentNode.addEventListener("click", function() {
    slct = this.textContent
    document.getElementById("slct").textContent = slct
  })
}
```

```css
.tree {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0;
  padding: 4px;
}

.active {
  display: block !important;
}

.branch {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
}

.folder {
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  overflow: clip;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
  filter: invert(74%) sepia(99%) saturate(730%) hue-rotate(357deg) brightness(100%) contrast(104%);
}

.file {
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  overflow: clip;
  padding: 6px;
  text-align: center;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
  filter: invert(74%) sepia(99%) saturate(730%) hue-rotate(357deg) brightness(100%) contrast(104%);
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
}

.cont {
  width: 100%;
  border-style: solid;
  background-color: #dea002;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">

  <ul class="tree">
    <li>
      <div class="div"><i class="folder"></i>&nbsp;Hello</div>
      <ul class="branch">
        <li class="item"><i class="file"></i>&nbsp;Hi</li>
        <li>
          <div class="div"><i class="folder"></i>&nbsp;Folder</div>
          <ul class="branch">
            <li><i class="file"></i>&nbsp;File 1</li>
            <li><i class="file"></i>&nbsp;File 2</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><i class="file"></i>&nbsp;World</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<b>Selceted File: <code id="slct">None</code></b>
```

This format is comprehensive and is not glitchy and unusable.

Note: The html above is a more extensive version of the first example.

Answer (score -3):

I would use a table. The different columns represent deeper levels of indentation.

Comment: Tables are used to represent data (with columns and rows). Use it to represent a hierarchy is as ugly as the oldschool  `<table>` design. A list can't semantic fits in a table, sorry.

Comment: Well if he was representing something like a Tree-Table i think it would be acceptable

Comment: I don't think he wants a tree-table.. he wants structured tree and I don't think that is the reason of tables existence. List/struct is surely better than table no offence but I hate seeing tables being overly misused.